# How do you stretch an image with CSS?

Tags: html, image, css

I have the following css:

```
.mod.left {
background-image: url("http://www.myimage.jpg");
display: block;
height: 160px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 175px;
}
```

That corresponds to this HTML:

```
<div class="mod left"></div>
```

It results in this mess:

[image]

Is there a way to stretch an image to fit a div? Even at the expense of image quality? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can with the CSS3 property [background-size](http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm). But it's not widely supported at the moment.

Comment: It basically has full support for every browser that isn't IE. It only works in IE9.

Comment: If it works in IE9, it works in IE, right? ;-) It didn't probably work in every version of FF and Chrome either. But thanks for the feedback, I didn't know it is supported by so many browsers already.

Comment: For future reference: I use this site a lot to check browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: Damn, I keep forgetting that site exists. But it's really a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `background-size` CSS attribute for this.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <img src="yourImage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

div{width:300px; height:300px; overflow:hidden;} //example
img{width:100%;}
```

This way, the image will resize horizontally to cover your entire div.
Not setting the height, will make it automaticly resize proportionally.
I suggest you put `overflow:hidden;` on your div. If the image ratio is not the exactly the same, the exceed will be hidden.